# facebook api upload video, it returns code 6000, subcode 1363048, try again makes no sense

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, restfb

when upload video, the Facebook API response with this error:
ERROR: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: There was a problem uploading your video file. Please try again with another file. (code 6000, subcode 1363048) '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been reported in facebook bug
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1077535216239001/?join_id=f25dbc66f4619bc&locale=zh_TW